# Is there a reason comments won't allow better editing?

Tags: support, comments

It's very frustrating that once I have asked my question—and someone needs more details on my question—that the comments box only allows you to add so much text and not allow me to further add more code to explain to someone what I need. Is there a reason Stack Exchange has opted for this method of replies, rather than a more conventional "forum" type reply?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The way to do this on Stack Exchange is to edit your question with more detail. After all, this is where the detail belongs: in the question.

Stack Exchange, by definition, isn’t a *discussion* board. It’s a question => answer board. This is why comments don’t allow for (and discourage) extensive discussions.